# When testing error scenarios how do you configure JMeter to show these tests as passed

Tags: jmeter

I have some validations in my Rest API that will return 400 bad request.  I have added test cases in JMeter for these, however the Listeners (e.g. Tree view) show these as unsuccessful (Error Icon) because JMeter did not receive a 200 response.  Is there a way to indicate for a given HTTP request that 400 is the expected result.  I can add an assert but the tree view display still shows the red error icon.

Answer (score 1):

You verify the Response Code, `400` and the Response Message,`bad request` with [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).

Add two [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to the HTTP Request where you need to verify the error.

Let's say you want to verify the response code first. Select **Field to Test** as `Response Code` in the first Response Assertion. Select the `Ignore Status` field. Set the **Pattern Matching Rules** as `Equal`. Click **Add** button and type the response code to verify, `400`.

[image]

Please ensure the `Ignore Status` is selected only in the first assertion.

[image]

In the second Response Assertion we shall verify the response message. Select the **Field to Test** as `Response Message`, **Pattern Matching Rules** as `Contains`, click the **Add** button and the add the regular expression to check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because JMeter automatically treats responses with [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) above 399 as failures.

If you expect [HTTP Status Code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) and would like to mark the request(s) as passed - add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) and configure it to check that response code equals to 400 and additionally tick "Ignore Status" box:

[image]